# How to implement Graphs(Dta structure) in java?

Tags: java, graph

How many methods are there for implementing graphs?Please share the example too?

Answer (score 0):

There are many...
one

```
Class Graph<T>{
   T data;
   List<Graph<T>> adjacentNodes;
}
```

Two Arrays

```
int a[][] = new int[10][10];
markThedistance if there's a link between i and j in a[i][j]
```

Comment: can you please post any example,like complete code??

Answer (score 0):

use a tree like structure:

> class node {
>       List children=new ArrayList<>(); }